# 2 large text files, find the lines that are not duplicate linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, comparison, duplicate

I am looking to find lines that are not duplicate, example;

Text file 1:

```
cats 3
dogs 8
mice 4
pigs 10
...
```

Text file 2:

```
dogs 8
mice 4
cats 78
pigs 29
bird 6
...
```

Cats and pigs simply got changed but are now different. Both files contain 'dogs 8' and 'mice 4' so output of different lines would be :

```
cats 78
pigs 29
bird 6
```

I was hopefully looking for a way this could be done in linux terminal like;
command input1.txt input2.txt diffrences.txt

Comment: Your example shows only the lines that are in file 2 but not file 1, but that is not what your question says. Please make the question and the example consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are nicely sorted you could do something as simple as this.

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

If the files are not sorted, and you want to find unique lines you might do something like this instead.

```
diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Given your above files the you would see this.

```
$ diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
--- /dev/fd/63  2014-09-19 15:40:20.223409721 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2014-09-19 15:40:20.219409761 -0700
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-cats 3
+bird 6
+cats 78
 dogs 8
 mice 4
-pigs 10
+pigs 29
```

> is there a way to get the '+' outputs only and not all the '-' lines etc,

Sure just pile it through grep.

```
$ diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | grep '^+'
+++ /dev/fd/62  2014-09-19 15:50:18.293474221 -0700
+bird 6
+cats 78
+pigs 29
```

Comment: the text lines would be random but some would be duplicate in there

Comment: is there a way to get the '+' outputs only and not all the '-' lines etc, thnaks for helping

Comment: can this handle large files gb's sizes?

Comment: `can this handle large files gb's sizes?` - It can, but it will potentially be slow.  The slowest part will be the sorting of large files.  I have used this to compare fairly large log files.  I updated the question to include  filtering example.

Comment: is there a way to save it straight out without grep? with just a single command?